# What is wrong with this end?

Tags: python, input, delay

I was going through a tutorial about defining functions with an example on creating new lines, and the code you had to write was this:

```
def new_line():
    print

def three_lines():
    new_line()
    new_line()
    new_line()

def nine_lines():
    three_lines()
    three_lines()
    three_lines()

print "hello world"

print nine_lines()

print "goodbye"
```

Could anybody explain why it includes 'None' before 'goodbye'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
print nine_lines()
```

You are printing the *result* of calling the `nine_lines()` function. Since that function does not *explicitly* return a value (using the `return` statement, if you haven't seen that yet then you will soon), Python returns the special value `None`.

To fix this, change that line to simply

```
nine_lines()
```

Comment: I don't even know why I put a 'print' in there when there isn't one in the tutorial haha, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`nine_lines()` will return None by default since you didn't specify a return value.

Just using

```
nine_lines()
```

Should give you the desired output or alternatively you could just use

```
print "\n" * 8
```

EDIT:  I changed the 9 to an 8.  I forgot that print also adds a new line character.  Thanks to Sven for pointing it out.

Comment: The last line will print 10 newline characters. :)

Comment: If you want more readability, there's always `print '\n' * 9,`

Answer (score 1):

When you run the function `nine_lines()` it does not return anything, which means it returns `None`.  Because you've printed the return value, you see None in the console.

Comment: Ah ok, so it will return the nine spaces and then print None because nine_lines contains no characters?

Comment: No, it does not *return* nine blank lines, it *prints* them. Then it *returns* `None` (because all functions return `None` if you don't return anything else). This is then printed.